I cannot find the TextEdit/ComboBox/MemoText properties in the skin editor VCL DevExpress
I tried to find in the editors, common, bars, navbar, etc and i dont find the properties to edit/textedit.
I'm using VCL skin editor by DevExpress in my Delphi project.
Can someone that use DevExpress skin editor help me?

You don't mention what properties you are trying to change. There is some abstraction of the color/state palette from skin elements to allow the same skin to be used with multiple color palettes.

Ask DevExpress support

DevEx has their own support forums, which are available to all licensed users. Have you asked for help there?
